# ActionwithAction and ActionwithDuration method giving error

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have an old code .I am trying to port it to new version of Cocos2dx It is giving me errors in the following lines.

```
CCSequence * pulseSequence = CCSequence::actionOneTwo(CCFadeIn::actionWithDuration(1), CCFadeOut::actionWithDuration(1));
CCRepeatForever* repeatAction = CCRepeatForever::actionWithAction(pulseSequence);
```

In ActiononeTwo, ActionwithDuration, and ActionwithAction method.It is telling me they are not the part of CCSequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CCSequence * pulseSequence = CCSequence::createWithTwoActions(CCFadeIn::create(1), CCFadeOut::create(1));
CCRepeatForever* repeatAction = CCRepeatForever::create(pulseSequence);
```

This should work.